# Prevent a big number from being formated like this "24.000.000"

Tags: c++, iostream

I am inserting some `int`s in my `ostream` but big numbers or even years, like `3000` or `25000123` are being formatted like this `3.000` or `25.000.123`.

I am not sure why this is happening. It might be because I usedd `imbue("")` on the stream so decimal numbers were shown like this `14,53` instead of `14.53` but I commented that line and everything stays the way it was.

I just want to get rid of those dots when getting numbers in the outstream (but I don't want to get rid of the decimal comma either). How can I do this?

I thought maybe the `iomanip` library would help but I didn't find anything regarding this situation.

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Article& a) {
    os << a.title() << a.pub_date().year() << ". " << a.price() << "";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: sure but it doesn't say much

Comment: You may want to [change you locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale).

Comment: Have you modified the stream's locale in any way? If not, you may have to install your own custom `numpunct` facet that does away with this kind of formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using `imbue` if you specify a custom grouping for numbers.

See an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/grouping/

Taking that example we have this code which verifies that no grouping is done even though the locale is set.

```
// numpunct::grouping example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::numpunct, std::use_facet

// custom numpunct with grouping:
struct my_numpunct : std::numpunct<char> {
    // the zero by itself means do no grouping
    std::string do_grouping() const {return "\0";}
};

int main() {
    std::locale loc (std::cout.getloc(),new my_numpunct);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << "one million: " << 1000000 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, you just beat me to it. You may as well add the demical stuff that the OP likes, just to make sure `char do_decimal_point() const { return ','; }` as it isn't really worth a separate answer.

Comment: His locale was probably already doing the right thing for decimals, that is why he used ``imbue`` in the first place. But yeah, the explicit use commas would be a good idea.

Comment: Its a potentially useful or interesting thing for anyone happening on this question in the future. But certainly not important.